# $\Delta ABC$, $AC = 2BC$ and $\angle C = 90^\circ$ and $D$ is the foot of the altitude from $C$ onto $AB$. Find $AE : EC$ .

Tags: geometry, triangles, problem-solving, congruences-geometry

> $\Delta ABC$, $AC = 2BC$ and $\angle C = 90^\circ$ and $D$ is the foot of the altitude from $C$ onto $AB$. A circle with diameter $AD$ intersects the segment $AC$ at $E$. Find $AE : EC$.

**What I Tried**: Here is a picture :-

[image]

The first thing I did was use similarity. For example one can find multiple similar triangles like $\Delta ABC \sim \Delta ACD \sim \Delta CBD$. After assuming $AC = x$ and $AD = y$ we get everything there in the picture.

Next from Pythagorean Theorem we will get only one equation involving $x$ and $y$ :-
$$5y^2 = x^2$$

The problem is, how will I proceed finding $AE$ and $ED$ ? I am thinking that $ED \parallel BC$ , but I have no proof of it and neither I cannot proceed further.

Can anyone help me? Thank You.

Comment: Note that $\angle DEA = 90^{\circ}$

Comment: @A.J. how will you prove it? That is the same as proving $ED \parallel BC$ .

Comment: $\angle DEA$ is inscribed in a semi-circle.

Comment: $AD$ is a diameter so you can use [Thales' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem).

Comment: I see I am late to it. Perp from $D$ to $AC$ meets at $E$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\angle AED$ must be $90^{\circ}$ as it is inscribed in a semi-circle. Thus $\triangle ADE \sim \triangle ABC$ and so

$$\frac{AE}{EC} = \frac{AD}{DB} = 4$$

Comment: Great, I got it. Missed out a small part on that $90^\circ$ angle and everything else I did was fine.

Answer (score 2):

$\angle DEA = 90º$ by [Thales' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem), so $\angle CED = 90º$.

Thus $\Delta DCE \sim \Delta CBD$ by AA. This gives:

$$\frac{EC}{CD} = \frac{DB}{DC} \Rightarrow \frac{EC}{2y} = \frac{y}{x}.$$

Write out $AC:EC$ for convenience in terms of $x,y$. Now using the fact that $5y^2 =x^2$:

$$\frac{AC}{EC} = \frac{2x}{2y^2/x} = \frac{x^2}{y^2} = 5.$$

Therefore $AE:EC$ is:

$$\frac{AC-EC}{EC} = \frac{5-1}{1} = \boxed{4}.$$